# Show that the sequence $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\dfrac{a^2_{n}}{n^2}$ is upper bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be defined with $a_{1}\in(0,1)$, and 
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\dfrac{a^2_{n}}{n^2}$$
for all $n\gt 0$.  Show that the sequence is  upper bounded.

My idea: since 
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}\left(1+\dfrac{a_{n}}{n^2}\right)$$
then
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}-\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+n^2}$$
then
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}-\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+n^2}$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}-\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{a_{i}+i^2}$$
since
$$a_{n+1}>a_{n}\Longrightarrow \dfrac{1}{a_{i}+i^2}<\dfrac{1}{a_{1}+i^2}$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}>\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}-\left(\dfrac{1}{1+a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{2^2+a_{1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{1}+n^2}\right)$$
But the RHS might be $\lt0$ for a sufficiently large starting value; for instance, with $a_{1}=\dfrac{99}{100}$
then
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}-\left(\dfrac{1}{1+a_{1}}+\dfrac{1}{2^2+a_{1}}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{1}+n^2}\right)<0,n\to\infty$$

see:
[image]

so this method won't let me bound the series and I don't know what else to do.

Comment: since $a_1\in (0,1)$ your sequence is obviously bounded from below by, e.g. $0$. I don't think there's an upper bound.

Comment: Have you looked at the trend of values of the sequence for various starting values?  Since it seems highly likely that the upper bound will go to $\infty$ as $a_1\to 1$, being able to conjecture a form for the upper bound in terms of $a_1$ (e.g., that the sequence is bounded by $(1-a_1)^{-1}$ or something similar) might help with a proof.

Comment: My idea: we must prove this $a_{n}>f(a_{1})?$

Comment: @math110 Actually, I think you want to prove the opposite: that $a_n\lt f(a_1)$ for some appropriate $f$.  Preliminary browsing around Alpha suggests that $a_n$ may in fact (slowly) converge to something like $1+(1-a_1)^{-1}$, so that might be an angle to start with.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a solution: Since $(a_{n})$ is monotone increasing, either it remains bounded or it diverges to $+\infty$. Assume that $a_{n} \nearrow +\infty$.

**Observation 1.** Referring to OP's identity

$$ \frac{1}{a_{n}} - \frac{1}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{1}{a_{n} + n^{2}}, $$

we have

$$ \frac{1}{a_{n}} - \frac{1}{a_{m+1}} = \sum_{k=n}^{m} \frac{1}{a_{k} + k^{2}}. $$

Taking $m \to \infty$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a_{n}}
= \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{k} + k^{2}}
\leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{2} - k}
= \frac{1}{n-1}.
\end{align*}

Thus we must have $n-1 \leq a_{n}$ for any $n \geq 2$.

**Observation 2.** Now we prove that $a_{n} \leq a_{1} n$ for any $n$. Indeed, this is trivial when $n = 1$. Also, if it holds for $n$ then

$$ a_{n+1} = a_{n} \left( 1 + \frac{a_{n}}{n^{2}} \right) \leq n a_{1} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) = (n+1)a_{1}. $$

Therefore by induction, we have the desired estimate.

**Conclusion.** Combining two observation, it follows that

$$n - 1 \leq a_{n} \leq na_{1} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad 1 - \frac{1}{n} \leq a_{1}.$$

for $n \geq 2$. Taking $n\to\infty$, we have $1 \leq a_{1}$, a contradiction! Therefore $(a_{n})$ must remain *bounded*.

---

**Addendum.** Now let us investigate an asymptotic behavior of the limit $f(a_{1}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_{n}$. We have

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a_{1}} - \frac{1}{f(a_{1})}
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2} + a_{n}}
\geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2} + n}
= 1,
\end{align*}

So we have a lower bound.

$$ f(a_{1}) \geq \frac{a_{1}}{1 - a_{1}}. $$

Comment: I think the last line should be $1\leq a_2$ ($n\geq 2$). And $1\leq a_2$ is no contradiction.

Comment: @pisoir, have you read Observation 2 carefully?

Comment: Very nice. +1. $ $

Comment: @sos440 Maybe I am missing something, but in Obser.2 you showed that e.g. $a_2\leq 2a_1$. And conclusion is that e.g. $1\leq a_2\leq 2a_1$. For $n=1$, you showed $0\leq a_1 \leq a_1$. I'm sorry I don't see any contradiction.

Comment: @pisoir, the contradiction occurs when $n$ gets large. Indeed, dividing both sides of $n-1 \leq a_{1}n$ by $n$, we have $$ 1 - \frac{1}{n} \leq a_{1}. $$ Taking $n\to\infty$, this inequality becomes $1 \leq a_{1}$. This *is* a contradiction.

Comment: Amazingly clever - I'm not sure I've ever seen a convergence proven by contradiction this way before!  It would be interesting to try and get an explicit bound on the limit in terms of $a_1$.

Comment: Thank you for sos440 solution,But my problem is prove upper bounded,because @StevenStadnicki edit my problem, yesterday I have prove upper bounded.Thank you

Comment: @math110, My solution proves that $(a_{n})$ is indeed bounded above. But unlike your solution, my one does not give explicit bound for the sequence. It just proves the *existence* of the bound.

Comment: @sos440 What is the meaning of $a_{n} \nearrow +\infty$? Is it any different from $a_n \to +\infty$ ?

Comment: @learner, it means that $a_{n}$ is monotone increasing and diverges to $+\infty$. Some also uses the notation $a_{n} \uparrow +\infty$.

Comment: @sos440 thank you so much sir for the clarification..

Answer (score 6):

Now,today I have solve this problem,I post my methods,I hope is not wrong?

since
$$a_{n+1}=a_{n}\left(1+\dfrac{a_{n}}{n^2}\right)$$
then
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}-\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+n^2}$$
then
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n}}-\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+n^2}$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}-\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{a_{i}+i^2}$$
so
$$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{a_{1}}-\left(\dfrac{1}{a_{1}+1^2}
+\dfrac{1}{a_{2}+2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{a_{n}+n^2}\right)$$
 by induction,we have
 $$a_{n}>nt^{n+1},t=\sqrt{a_{1}}\in (0,1)$$
 because
 $$a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\dfrac{a^2_{n}}{n^2}>nt^{n+1}+t^{2n+2}$$
 we only prove
 $$nt^{n+1}+t^{2n+2}>(n+1)t^{n+2},t=\sqrt{a_{1}}\in (0,1)$$
 $$\Longleftrightarrow n+t^{n+1}-(n+1)t>0$$
 use this Bernoulli inequality:
 $$(1+x)^n\ge 1+nx,x>-1,n>1$$
 then we have
 $$t^{n+1}=(1+t-1)^{n+1}>1+(n+1)(t-1)=1+(n+1)t-(n+1)$$
 Now $$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}>\dfrac{1}{t^2}-\left(\dfrac{1}{t^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{2t^3+2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{nt^{n+1}+n^2}\right)$$
 other hand,Use AM-GM inequality,we have
 \begin{align*}
 \dfrac{1}{t^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{2t^3+2^2}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{nt^{n+1}+n^2}&=\dfrac{1}{1(1+t^2)}+\dfrac{1}{2(1+1+t^3)}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n(1+1+\cdots+1+t^{n+1})}\\
 &<\dfrac{1}{2t}+\dfrac{1}{2\times 3t}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)t}\\
 &=\dfrac{1}{t}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
 &<\dfrac{1}{t}
 \end{align*}
 so
 $$\dfrac{1}{a_{n+1}}>\dfrac{1}{t^2}-\dfrac{1}{t}$$
 $$\Longrightarrow a_{n+1}<\dfrac{t^2}{1-t}$$

Comment: +1 I checked your solution and was unable to find out any error. So, be proud of your solution! :)

Comment: The bound is actually very very good. I simulated the recurrence equation for various $a_1$ and the bound is almost touching the true steady state ,i.e. $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\approx a_1\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{a_1}}$$ ([see pic](http://i61.tinypic.com/xpuiib.jpg)). Maybe there exists even an analytical solution...;)

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = 1 + \frac{a_n}{n^2}$$

Therefore, if the product
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} ( 1+ \frac{a_n}{n^2})$$
is bounded, then so is $a_n$. Since $1+x \le e^x$, it is enough to show that $\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{a_n}{n^2} < \infty$. Now, this would follow from $\frac{a_n}{n} < n^{1-\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$.

Now, for the sequence $b_n\colon = \frac{a_n}{n}$ we have
$$b_{n+1} = \frac{n b_n + b_n^2}{n+1}$$
so by induction $1 > b=b_1 > b_2 > \ldots > 0$.  Now we have
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \frac{1+ \frac{b_n}{n} }{1 + \frac{1}{n}}$$

Now, the partial products of the infinite  product
$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1 + \frac{b}{n}}{1 + \frac{1}{n}}$$
decrease like $n^{b-1}$. We are done.

$\bf{Added:}$ A similar argument shows that the sequence of holomorphic function $\phi_1(z) =z$, $\phi_{n+1}(z) = \phi_n(z) + (\frac{\phi_n(z)}{n})^2$,  converges uniformly on compacts to a holomorphic function $\phi(z)$ on the unit disk $D(0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

When the exponent is $\alpha,\alpha \gt 1$, the proof is as follows.
$$ 
\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{a_n^\alpha}=\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\\
$$
then $\sum_{n=M}^\infty\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{a_n^\alpha}$ converges.
Let $T_N=\sum_{n=M}^N\frac{a_{n+1}-a_{n}}{a_n^\alpha}, N\ge M,T_N$ is monotonically increasing.
$$\begin{align}
T_N&=\sum_{n=M}^N\int_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}}\frac{dx}{a_n^\alpha}\\&\gt\sum_{n=M}^N\int_{a_n}^{a_{n+1}}\frac{dx}{x^\alpha}\\&=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(a_{N+1}^{1-\alpha}-a_{M}^{1-\alpha})\\
T_N&=\sum_{n=M}^N\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\\&\lt\sum_{n=M}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\\&=\frac{1}{M^{\alpha}}+\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}\\&\lt\frac{1}{M^{\alpha}}+\sum_{n=M+1}^{\infty}\int_{n-1}^n\frac{dx}{x^{\alpha}}\\&=\frac{1}{M^{\alpha}}+\frac{M^{1-\alpha}}{\alpha-1}\end{align}
$$
there is an inequality:
$$
\frac{1}{1-\alpha}(a_{N+1}^{1-\alpha}-a_{M}^{1-\alpha})\lt\frac{1}{M^{\alpha}}+\frac{M^{1-\alpha}}{\alpha-1}\\
\Rightarrow a_{N+1}^{1-\alpha}\gt a_{M}^{1-\alpha}-(\alpha-1)M^{-\alpha}-M^{1-\alpha}
$$
we need to show $a_{M}^{1-\alpha}-(\alpha-1)M^{-\alpha}-M^{1-\alpha}\gt 0$. Notes $a_n\lt na_1$, then
$$
(Ma_1)^{1-\alpha}\lt a_M^{1-\alpha}\\
\Rightarrow a_{M}^{1-\alpha}-(\alpha-1)M^{-\alpha}-M^{1-\alpha}\gt (Ma_1)^{1-\alpha}-(\alpha-1)M^{-\alpha}-M^{1-\alpha}\\\gt 0
$$
Iff
$$
M\gt \frac{\alpha-1}{a_1^{1-\alpha}-1}
$$

Comment: Please do not include an image as your answer and instead use MathJax.

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Thanks all! I've changed my answer into MathJax form