# Find $\lim a_n$ if $a_{n+1}=a_n+\frac{a_n^2}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

$0\lt a_1\lt 1$, $a_{n+1}=a_n+\dfrac{a_n^2}{n^2}$,

Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$

---

Well,  $a_{n+1}\gt a_n$, But how to show that there is  an upper bound of $\{a_n\}$ ? What is the limit ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: It is a sequence of positive numbers.So if we assume that the limit exits , and calculate the limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ , then it is easily seen to be 0 , and so the required limit is 0.

Comment: @HirenGarai How does one arrive at that conclusion?  It isn't correct.

Comment: @HirenGarai No, the limit is not $0$. For $a_1=1/2$ it seems to be $\ln 2$. Also, OP proved that the sequence is increasing...

Comment: Yes, My mistake, the limit of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ is not 0, .. so the required limit is not 0..

Comment: There are a couple of postings which answer the convergence part, see [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672888/prove-the-existence-of-limit-of-x-n1-x-n-dfracx-n2n2) and [**this**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680938/show-that-the-sequence-a-n1-a-n-dfraca2-nn2-is-upper-bounded). Regarding the closed-form part, I once studied the limit as function of the initial term, and if I remember correctly the function seems to develop a lacunary boundary. This makes me suspect that no simple closed form can ever be found.

Comment: @mickep for $a_1 = 0.5 $ limit seem to be $1.341...$

Comment: @RaghukulRaman Indeed, my value was wrong. I accidentaly looked at $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}^2/n^2$ or something similar. Well, then I take that part of my comment back. Thanks!

Comment: @SangchulLee  Thank you very much!   I  searched, but   no  results.......

Comment: does this sequence even converge?? I enumerated the value for $a_1 = 0.99999$ and I found that $a_{50000} = 35162$.

Comment: @RaghukulRaman, As shown in the link, if $a_1$ is close to $1$ then the limit is approximately $\frac{2}{1-a_1}$. In your case, this is $200000$ so your observation is not surprising.